# Hardy Weinberg equilibrium

Tags: homework, hardy-weinberg

> Hardy Weinberg would predict that the frequency of normal females, to carrier females,
>   to affected females for colorblindness is equal to p$^2$ + 2pq + q$^2$=1. You
>   were told that q=freq of the recessive allele. If p+q =1 (frequency of the dominant allele +
>   frequency of the recessive allele=1 or 100%) and q=.08, what is the frequency of the
>   normal allele in the population? What is the frequency of carrier females in the
>   population (ie heterozygous females)?

I get that the frequency of the normal allele is p = 1 - .08 so 0.92. However the frequency of carrier females is giving me an unrealistic number. Using p$^2$ + 2pq + q$^2$ =1, the value for pq comes out to be a negative value. Is it safe to just multiply p and q since that is what we're essentially solving for using the full HW equation? This would make the value (.08*.92) = 0.0736. Would that be the way to approach the problem even though it asks for females only?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Homework questions are off-topic on Biology unless you have shown your attempt at an answer. For more information see our [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework).

Comment: Btw, although the question is quite clear, the phrasing is a bit inaccurate and misleading. Is it the question as written for your homework?

Comment: Yes, that is the exact wording of the problem!

Comment: check your math, `the value for pq comes out to be a negative value` is incorrect

Comment: Thank you, got the value to be .0736. Would this be correct as to being the frequency of carrier females?

Answer (score 2):

Carrier females= 2pq= 2 x .08 x 0.92

Because carriers say with genotype  Aa (A=dominant, a=recessive)  can arise due to two types of inheritances;one when A is from father and a is from mother and the other when it is just opposite.